# Media query not working on opera mini browser but works fine on firefox and chrome browser

Tags: html, css, frontend

Here is a snippet of my CSS code for the media query:

```
@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) {

.vertical-bar{
    display: none;
}

.fa-bars{
    position: fixed;
    left:280px;
    top: 20px;
}

.fa-bars.animate{
    top: -71px;
}

.fa-bars.sticky{
    top: 25px;
}

}
```

The code works fine on both mobile chrome and Firefox but not on opera. I do not know why. Is there any special keyword for opera I'm missing to include in my CSS code? Please help me.

Comment: check this out previous answered question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21441993/media-queries-doesnt-work

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [Modernizr](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr), or [Respond](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond);

Just see the documentation provided in the documents if you really want to do it.

These two repositories that I have mentioned above will take care of everything

Comment: And these will help you too (Sorry, don't have enough reputation to comment on your post) 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10185904/media-queries-in-opera-mini-incorrect-display

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10246903/css3-media-queries-does-not-work-in-some-browsers-officially-supporting-mq